# Slick Slider Regex filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, slick.js

I am trying to have a slider, which has a search box accompanied with it. This search box searches names of users in the slider.

Currently, the search box has an autocomplete to complete their full name when a user begins to type in the input box.

For example, they type 'Joh' and 'John Doe' is recommended.

If they click on the 'John Doe' recommendation, then the search will work fine and return john, but if they press enter or press the submit button, then it will show no one.

Is there a way in slick that allows me to filter with regex.

Example: A user types 'Joh' and presses enter. It then returns with 'John Doe', 'Johnathon Pete', 'Daniel Johns'

Thanks

Comment: On submit `search box contents` + `.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I used James Padolsey's Regex Selector for jquery.

Here is my final filter statement:

```
var key = $name_query;
$('.carousel').slick('slickFilter', $('.member:regex(id,.*' + key + '.*)')).slick('refresh');
```